# How to get correct div innerHeight the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I have a hidden sub nav with height set to 0. Inside of that div are several sections of sub navs.

I get the name of the section that is clicked, then get the innerHeight of that div. Then using that height, I animate the `.sub_navigation` height from 0 to the value. However for some reason the first time you click (get the value) it's off, too high, the 2nd time it's perfect.

How would you fix this?

---

*Angular (converted from jQuery)*

```
// Controller for Nav
app.controller('NavController', function(){
    // Property of Controller

    this.clicked = function(menuItem) {
        console.log(menuItem);

        var contentHeight = $('.'+menuItem+'-content').innerHeight();
        var content_height = $('.'+menuItem+'-content').innerHeight();

        $('.sub_navigation').css({'height' : '0px'});
        $('.'+menuItem+'-content').siblings().css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('.'+menuItem+'-content').css({'display':'block', 'height':'auto'});
        $('.sub_navigation').animate({
            height: contentHeight
        });

        console.log('content_height = '+content_height);
        console.log(contentHeight);
    };
});
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).delegate(".navigation-links a", "click", function(){
    var myContent = $(this).attr("data-content");
    var contentHeight = $("."+myContent+"-content").innerHeight();

    $("."+myContent+"-content").siblings().css({"display":"none"});
    $("."+myContent+"-content").css({"display":"block", "height":"auto"});
    $(".subNavigation").animate({
        height: contentHeight
    });
});
```

If you click on Grow, the first time height is 400, the 2nd time it's 266 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The innerHeight [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) says that:

> The value reported by `.innerHeight()` is not guaranteed to be accurate
>   when the element's parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, you
>   should show the parent first, before using `.innerHeight()`.

So although the parent is visible, maybe the fact that the element itself is invisible makes the height value to be inaccurate.

Have you tried, changing the order?

```
//Make the sub menu visible first
$('.'+menuItem+'-content').siblings().css({'display' : 'none'});
$('.'+menuItem+'-content').css({'display':'block', 'height':'auto'});

var contentHeight = $('.'+menuItem+'-content').innerHeight();
var content_height = $('.'+menuItem+'-content').innerHeight();

$('.sub_navigation').css({'height' : '0px'});
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to show the menuItem while getting the height:

```
this.clicked = function(menuItem) {
  var menu = $('.'+menuItem+'-content');
  menu.show();
  var contentHeight = menu.outerHeight();
  menu.hide();
  ...
```